# How do I convert height px to % so my page is responsive on resize?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive grid using the max-width of 980px to convert my fixed PX widths to % but I'm unsure what I have to do to update the heights also set in PX to %. Can anyone advise on how this can be achieved? I've tried to set height to `max-height:300px; height:100%` but with no success.

**Js Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/5jJQk/

**Example CSS**

```
#ctn{
  max-width: 980px; /* 960 */
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: left;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col{
  background: #b7b7b7;
  max-height: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 1.041666667%; /* 10/960 */
  float: left;
}

.four{
  width: 31.25%; /* 300/960 */
}

.eight{
  width: 64.583333333%; /* 620/960 */
}

.twelve{
  width: 97.916666667%; /* 940/960 */
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: You can learn media queries and have a css for each kind of resolution. It's hard to set a height for a container when you don't know the sum of the size of the content.

Comment: hey yeah i understand I can use media queries but was hoping I could use % width and height to naturally scale the .col elements naturally then use the media query when I need to change things up a little

Answer (score 2):

`height` in percentage only works if the parent element has defined height, or it's in percentages all the way up to the root element.

See what happens when you add

```
html, body, #ctn { height:100%; }
```

to your CSS.

However, defining height is only necessary in very specific cases. Usually you want blocks to accommodate to their content.

Comment: adding height 100% to html, body and #ctn works great, only problem is that when I resize the browser my .col elements dont seem to scale down in height instead they are still fixed at the max-height:300px? shouldnt this height reduce if redcing the screensize down?

Comment: Messing with height isn't really a good idea, especially in what seems to be a general-purpose grid. But yes, it'll stay at its max-height (try to remove max-height it and see what happens then!). Why dou you need to set height? Maybe there are other options, like display:table-* or flex-box?

Comment: think i just found something that may help me http://dinosaurswithlaserz.com/2011/07/18/fluid-squares-v2/ thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It's quite clever, but keep in mind it only works with limited amount of content. If you put too much text into a square it will get "clipped" due to `overflow:hidden`. This is one of the specific cases I've had in mind in my original response, as it's not universal solution, but works for specific amount of content + element dimensions combination.

Comment: yeah I understand about the complications so will see how things go, I really only want to use this solution in a limited grid if I even use it at all. At the moment I'm just curious about whether or not this can be done. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would look into media queries, they work really well when converting.

http://mediaqueri.es/

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

I hope this helps.